# Converting String to date format in R

Tags: r

I have a string as follows

```
11MAY2018:00:00:00.000
```

Can this be converted to the following formats

i) 11-May-2018

ii) May-2018 or 05-2018

Answer (score 4):

You can use `lubridate` package to turn your string into a date format and then use some functions like `year`, `month`, `day` to extract relevant information and combine them using `paste0`:

```
library(lubridate)

x = "11MAY2018:00:00:00.000"
y = dmy_hms(x)

paste0(c(day(y),as.character(month(y, label = T)),year(y)), collapse = "-")
# [1] "11-May-2018"

paste0(c(as.character(month(y, label = T)),year(y)), collapse = "-")
# [1] "May-2018"

paste0(c(month(y),year(y)), collapse = "-")
# [1] "5-2018"
```

Comment: Instead of extracting the information you can also use : `format(y, format = "%d-%b-%Y")`, `format(y, format = "%b-%Y")`, `format(y, format = "%m-%Y")`

Answer (score 2):

It should work as well:

```
str<-"11MAY2018:00:00:00.000"
dt<-substring(str, c(1), c( 9))

as.Date(dt,format='%d%b%Y')
```

https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

Comment: You can use `substring(str, 1, 9)`, without the `c(.)`. But your output seems to be `"2020-05-11"`. It works with `as.Date(dt,format='%d%b%Y')` (capital Y)

Comment: This only works for this one case, but not if you have different months

Comment: @AntoniosK i have no idea from where it comes to `2020`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your format specification is not totally correct, `%y`looks for only a two-digit year, you need `%Y` as @AntoniosK already said

Comment: @kath i have tried it for `"11SEP2018:00:00:00.000"`, and it works well. So, why do you think, it does not work for different monthes?

Comment: What about "11APRIL2018:00:00:00.000"? From the example you can't assume abbreviated months. I don't want to say that your solution is wrong, only that there might be problems... Nevertheless I like solutions without extra-packages